# Java Applet Blocked

Tags: java, applet, blocked

I'm trying to make an applet work on my website but whenever I load it, I get the following message: Your security settings have blocked an untrusted application from running.
I have added the site to exception list, but it still won't work.
What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's actually nothing to do with teachers. I was trying to make my Java game work on my website for fun.

Comment: If you want to make a game available from a link on your web site, make it in a `JFrame` and launch it (from the link) using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It will be *much easier* that deploying an applet.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The game uses LWJGL and it's Display class to create a window, so it's not using JFrame. Can I launch an LWJGL game the same way?

Comment: You sure can..  I just mentioned `JFrame` since that is the most common 'main window' used by desktop Swing apps.

Comment: @AndrewThompson First of all, thanks for helping. I kind of made it work (I have a jnlp file I can launch) but there's one problem. It seems like I have to sign my jars, which is the same problem I had with applets. I have tried to sign them a couple of times, but I haven't succeeded. If I'm not wrong, I would have to pay for a certificate which isn't really an option for me. Is there a way to use JWS without signing the jars? if not, can I sign them for free?

Comment: I also tried to change the permissions to "none", which worked, except now if I run the game, I get the following error: 'access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "org.lwjgl.util.Debug" "read")'. It seems like the game requires elevated permissions. However, I would need to sign the jars and I cannot do it, like I said in the previous comment.

Comment: *"Is there a way to use JWS without signing the jars?"*  Given that applets are required to be digitally signed for **user security reasons** what sense would there be in forcing applets to be signed, but not JWS based apps.?  *"which is the same problem I had with applets."*  Oh no.  You'll have a lot more problems than that with applets.  Many browsers put extra barriers for launching applets that don't apply to  downloaded things like the JNLP file for JWS Apps.  ..

Comment: .. *"can I sign them for free?"*  There was an eastern European company giving out free certificates a while ago, so long as the code was open source, but I cannot immediately recall who. *"I also tried to change the permissions.."*  Given you cannot do that for the users, and they **should not do it** themselves, that's really a dead-end.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign the applet using the official certificate that only some company involved in code signing can provide. If this is not an option for you, there is basically nothing you can do as Oracle has removed the possibility to run unsigned applets in a sandbox of the browser.

Comment: Well, the applet is mine and I have full access to its source code.

Comment: This is not helpful. You need a certificate authority to create the signature. Google for "Java applet signing certificate".